# How do you measure circular reasoning?

Tags: logic, fallacies

How do you measure circular reasoning?

Comment: Since one trip through the loop has the same effect as five or ten or a million, I would assume you cannot measure it.  There is so much proof then some number of cycles of unproductive nonsense, and then more proof.  The number of cycles is exactly what doesn't matter.

Comment: Perhaps by the number of distinct elements in the smallest self-referential chain. A->A has length 1, A->B->A has length 2, A->B->C->A has length 3, etc.

Comment: What exactly does it mean to "measure" circular reasoning?

Answer (score 2):

Douglas Walton provides a brief assessment of circular reason which may help to suggest "measures" of its use.

Walton first notes that one should not assume circular reason is always fallacious:

> Circular reasoning is very important and characteristic of all kinds of everyday argumentation where feedback is used. So it is often quite correct and useful — not fallacious, as traditionally portrayed in the logic textbooks.

So a first step in measuring circular reason is to determine if it is fallacious or not.
If we suspect it is fallacious we need criteria supporting that judgement.

Walton describes a fallacious use of circular reasoning as follows:

> Arguing in a circle becomes a fallacy of *petitio principii* or begging the question where an attempt is made to evade the burden of proving one of the premises of an argument by basing it on the prior acceptance of the conclusion to be proved (See Walton, 1991). So the fallacy of begging the question is a systematic tactic to evade fulfillment of a legitimate BURDEN OF PROOF by the proponent of an argument in dialogue by using a circular structure of argument to block the further progress of dialogue and, in particular, to undermine the capability of the respondent, to whom the argument was directed, to ask legitimate critical questions in reply.

This suggests criteria on how to measure or justify an assessment that an argument using circular reasoning is actually fallacious.

- To what extent is the use of circular reasoning a tactic that involves evasion of burden of proof?
- To what extent does this tactic block further progress of dialogue?
- Does this prevent the one subjected to a circular argument from asking legitimate critical questions?

---

Walton, D. "Circular Reasoning" entry in *A Companion to Epistemology*, ed. Jonathan Dancy and Ernest Sosa, Oxford, Blackwell, 1992, p. 66 Retrieved from Douglas Walton's site on August 21, 2019 at https://www.dougwalton.ca/papers%20in%20pdf/92CircReas.pdf

Comment: Do you have any example of how a circular argument would not be fallacious? Your link doesn't say. And there seems to be a very large consensus that it is always fallacious.

Comment: @Speakpigeon In proof systems such as natural deduction using the reiteration inference rule is a form of circular reasoning that is valid. It is not fallacious. In general, referencing a previously agreed upon premise to clarify it or confirm it would not be fallacious. In cross examinations a witness may be asked to confirm repeatedly their commitments to previously made statements to make sure they actually agree with them. The cross examination cannot stop there, but must drive home a contradiction between those prior commitments and something else.

Comment: Maybe some logicians call reiteration "circular" but it's clearly not circular in the same sense as the commonly used "circular" in the discussion of fallacious circular arguments. This seems a case of equivocation. I don't even understand what would be circular in reiteration.

Comment: Even the very best uses of circular reasoning, for instance analyses that just embed the concept in multiple domains without achieving a grounding (a la the observations of 'strange loops' via category theory in math, etc.) are logically inconclusive, but they increase the number of circumstantial observations.  So in that case the circular argument is not the reasoning, the application of different kinds of leverage to the problem is.  The value of the outcome is not dependent on the circles, but on the number of other dependencies noted through the embeddings.

Comment: @Frank hubney, the reiteration rule is NOT an example of circular reasoning. In the inference rule you are not justifying another proposition but just repeating what was stated above in a lengthy line proof. I am positive that if you have an 8 line proof you would use reiteration. Repeating the same proposition does nothing in terms of argument. Circular reasoning is arriving at a conclusion based on synonymous premises to the conclusion. In this way the conclusion is not established ever.  If the premise was true the conclusion would have to be true by definition.

Comment: @Speakpigeon Walton gives examples of what he means by "feedback" in [Are Circular Arguments Necessarily Vicious?](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20014107), e.g. "*the economy is depressed because people are leaving, and pople are leaving because the economy is depressed*". He even characterizes equivalence proofs in mathematics as "circular". After all, even "If A then A" is classically valid. When people call circularity an "informal" fallacy they acquiesce to being loose about what counts as it. So "always fallacious" wouldn't work, the "equivocation" is built in.

Comment: @Conifold Yes, I found the hoard of document Walton put on the Internet. Interesting but nothing about deductive logic as such. It's about the practice of arguments. So, it's really just equivocation. Also, "If A then A" is an implication, a valid one, but it's not an argument, so circularity and the fallacy of it are both irrelevant. And there is nothing loose about the fallacy of circularity, only the incredible fuzziness of our science of it, which I'm just discovering. Still, it's a very interesting question.

Comment: @Speakpigeon Deductive logic is but a husk of what arguments are, and any implication converts into a formal argument and vice-versa, by the [deduction meta-theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem), ironically. Equivocation does not apply here, the correct term is vagueness (of meaning), which "the fallacy of circularity" is a typical example of. For equivocation you need two distinct notions.

Comment: @Conifold And we do have two different notions. And so we disagree.

Comment: @Speakpigeon Sure. But there is no "very large consensus" that circularity is always fallacious, it's just you. Moreover, in formal arguments it is always valid (trivially).

Comment: @Conifold No, it's not just me. I based my comment on the fact that, using a search engine, I couldn't find anybody not saying explicitly that circular reasoning is fallacious. Except this Walton, and then reading what he says it was clear to me he is not talking about this from the perspective of deductive logic.

Comment: @Conifold Google search: 
"circular reasoning is fallacious"       3,350 hits
"circular reasoning is a fallacy"         6,590 hits
"circular reasoning is not fallacious"        7 hits
"circular reasoning is not a fallacy"          5 hits
Do the maths.

Comment: @Conifold  "*in formal arguments it is always valid (trivially)*" This is just not true. It is only true according to mathematical logic, so, in fact *not always*. There is nothing about formal arguments that says valid if circular. It all depends on the method you choose to use. And most people assessing a circular argument would say it is fallacious. Anyway, this is useless. You don't argue, you just repeat the mathematical logic dogma.

Comment: @Speakpigeon Your second and third sentences contradict each other, and comments are not for arguing. Just avoid "very large consensus" and "most people" when you comment here. "Most people" do not know what "circular" or "fallacious" means, and you are too unplugged from those who do to make such judgments, they are just misleading. Even your "mathematical logic" has your personal meaning.

Comment: @Conifold No, my 2nd and 3rd don't contradict each other. You are just making the wrong assumptions about them. There's also no connection, contrary to what you suggest here, between my "very large consensus" and my "most people", simply because those are not the same kind of people. Further, you would need to prove I'm wrong here. My Google search supports my assumption. And you're committing your own sweet fallacy: most people do not need to know what "circular reasoning" or "fallacious" mean to assess a circular reasoning as fallacious. Enough of this, we won't convince each other.

Comment: @Speakpigeon What connection? What proving? By Google? What difference does it make what people who do not know "assess"? Convince you, why would I try? More importantly, what was the point of posting the last comment?

Comment: @Conifold No point at all.